# Advise on locating elements on a webpage I am building a selenium script for

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am after some advice regarding a Selenium script I am building. The screenshot of the webpage I am writing the selenium scripts against, is attached[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ByM1.jpg). I have a webpage where I am mouse hovering over the ‘Reports’ text from the navigation pane which brings up a menu…..from that menu there I am selecting ‘Asset Management’, then ‘Terminated Report: Completed’ from the sub-menu.

I’ve attached the selenium code below which highlights what I am trying to do….I thought the best way to do this would be via xpath, as there wasn’t a great deal of information to work off in terms of elements.

```
public class optionFocusControls {

//REPORTS TAB   
public static void reportWindowFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement reportWindowFocus = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reports"));
    Actions hoverOnReportText = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportText.moveToElement(reportWindowFocus).build().perform();           
}

public static void assetManagementFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement assetManagementFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a"));     
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(assetManagementFocus).build().perform();
}

public static void daysInStockFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement daysInStockFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
    Actions hoverOnDaysInStock = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnDaysInStock.moveToElement(daysInStockFocus).build().perform();
    daysInStockFocus.click();
}


public static void terminatedReportCompletedFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement terminatedReportCompletedFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a"));      
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(terminatedReportCompletedFocus).build().perform();
    terminatedReportCompletedFocus.click();
}

}
```

I’ve also attached the HTML from the webpage (Screenshot 2, which hopefully gives an idea of how I built the above test scripts in Selnenium(apologies for the formatting!)

```
body class="customer-search">
<div id="wrapper">
<form id="aspnetForm" action="CustomerSearch.aspx" method="post">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<div id="top-nav">
<div class="inner">
<img id="ctl00_Img1" alt="*" src="../Images/chinook/gfx-topnav-left.gif">
<ul class="drop-down-menu sub-nav">
<li>
<li id="GN02">
<li id="GN03">
<li>
<a class="" href="../CCLReports/Overall">Reports</a>
<ul id="ddm-74938" style="display: none;">
<li>
<a class="" href="#">Asset Management</a>
<span>»</span>
<ul style="display: none;">
```

The issue I have had is that I want to arrive at the 'Asset Management' > 'Terminated Report: Completed' page. After I have checked that page I want to go to 'Asset Management' > 'Terminated  Report: Pending' page. However, the XPath when selecting the ‘Asset Management’ option is now different when I go to 'Terminated Report: Pending', than it was when I went to 'Terminated eReport: Completed', even thought the selection of it is the same..... I’m assuming this is because I am selecting the menu option from a different page, does this change the Xpath? Based on the above, I have two questions which I am hoping for assistance on:
 1) Given that it looks like XPath isn’t the best way of me navigating through this navigation menus, what would be the best element locator to use, in order to get to the desired location?
 2) Another issue I have is that when I arrive at a page, using the above selenium code, the focus is still on the option I have selected from the menu e.g. ‘Terminated Report: Completed’. This prevents me from being able to select any elements on the page, and I can’t see any way around this. Is there an action whereby the focus can be switched to the webpage as a whole, so I can complete any actions I need to.

Comment: Do you have any control over the HTML being generated on the site? Is the menu generated by a helper library or purely CSS controlled? There is a lot of nesting in the HTML snippet you posted and the XPath selectors could definitely run in to issues if the layout changes based on the page.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. No, I don't have any control over the HTML unfortunately. I'm assuming that the menu is generated via CSS, but is there a way of me being able to find the csslocators?

Comment: @AndyTilston you can use [imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload your screenshot and share with the community. It's free

Comment: Thanks Saifur, screenshot added here.....http://imgur.com/My9BA8c

Comment: If the menu HTML changes based on the page you are on then the XPath you have will probably not work. Worse case is match the text of the menu and see if that works `WebElement assetManagementFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Asset Management')]"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath and CssLocators are pretty flexible since they support multiple ways of identifying an element. I'm not sure you'll find a better alternative. [This](http://bit.ly/gTd5oc) is a good reference for what they can do.

Your approach is pretty rigid in that your xpath string specifies the full hierarchy - the element you're searching for plus all its parents. If any element in that hierarchy changes or gets re-ordered it will fail.

Based on your html snippet, the link text is the most unique key to identify our elements. This isn't ideal since we can come across other links with the same text, but we can use parent or sibling relations with other elements to improve robustness.

All our menu elements are in the top navigation bar so we can limit our search to its descendants. The unspecified path look up `//` lets us skip stating the full hierarchy chain and use a more generic relationship.

e.g.

```
public static void daysInStockFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement daysInStockFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='top-nav']//a[contains(text(),'Asset Management')]"));
    Actions hoverOnDaysInStock = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnDaysInStock.moveToElement(daysInStockFocus).build().perform();
    daysInStockFocus.click();
}

public static void terminatedReportCompletedFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver){
    WebElement terminatedReportCompletedFocus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='top-nav']//a[contains(text(),'Terminated Report: Completed')]"));      
    Actions hoverOnReportWindow = new Actions(driver);
    hoverOnReportWindow.moveToElement(terminatedReportCompletedFocus).build().perform();
    terminatedReportCompletedFocus.click();
}
```